# SQLAlchemy object update after UPDATE sql method

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I have a SQLAlchemy model that has an update method that executes an SQL query. However, after that, the object does not update its fields. What is the recommended way of updating those fields?
Model example:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    username: Mapped[str]
    
    async def update_username(self, session_maker:async_sessionmaker[AsyncSession], username:str) -> Optional['User']:
        update_sql = update(User).where(User.id==self.id).values(username = username)
        async with session_maker() as ses:
            result = await ses.execute(update_sql)
            await ses.commit()
        # what i should do next?
```

I have some ideas on how to achieve that:

1. After updating, get a new User object and return it (this does not feel right).
2. Manually update the current object, for example, `self.username = username` (however, I can't be sure that fields are the only difference between two objects of the same model).
3. I should not update the fields. After the update method is executed, the object will "expire", and I should make only one action with it.
4. Or I don't understand some core principles of SQLAlchemy and I'm doing something stupid.

Answer is option 2. It is safe to change variables by hand if you sure that it is in sync with db(after UPDATE query)

Comment: Option 2. If you have a specific instance of a User object (e.g., via `some_user = session.get(User, 1)` or whatever) then just update its username (`some_user.username = "new name"`) and then call `session.flush()` or `session.commit()`. SQLAlchemy will build and execute the DML (UPDATE statement) for you. Feel free to explain what you mean by "I can't be sure that fields are the only difference between two objects of the same model".